# Wordpress image and p parsing

Tags: wordpress, parsing

I have an image that should float right to the text, and it does, inside the main theme. However in a mobile theme, the source code in the end is

```
<p> <img /> </p>
<p> TEXT </p>
```

instead of

```
<p> <img /> TEXT </p>
```

Where and how could I fix this problem?

I am new to wp (i know php) and I am modifying themes someone else built, so I do not know too much. If this helps, the original theme is twenty ten and the mobile theme is called mobile pack base, so I guess I should see how the initial theme works and parses content, and then modify the mobile pack one, but I have no idea where to look

Comment: Is this an image that is part of the theme, or is it an image that is inserted in a post or page?

Comment: the image is part of a post so the p tags are added by the wp themes

Answer (score 0):

The extra paragraph is probably being added by `wpautop`. You can disable it by adding the following to your `functions.php` file.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); // Remove auto formatting in full content 
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' ); // Remove auto formatting in post excerpts
```

Comment: That did not work, thing is I have no idea where all the functions are being called from, there are too many both files and functions and I get confused with what is going on...

Comment: Do you have a live example that we can see anywhere? Or at least let us know which theme you are having the issue with?

Comment: I don't have an example because the dev blog can only be accessed from  the office building. The theme is mobile pack base, but the thing is someone actually edited it a bit before me, I compared the code I got to the original theme and it is missing quite some code in the index page for starters... I'll try and copy the theme to my own site and share the source code sometime tonight
Thanks